# ListView is not showing updates at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using Linq to SQL for Database operations in C# Windows Form application. I'm trying to update ListView data when User makes any update on the database. I've tried `listView.BeginUpdate()`, `listView.Refresh()`, `listView.EndUpdate()` methods to get updates but ListView updated data now showing in ListView. When I restart the application then it shows that data. I tried debug, Database gets update before I call `refreshListView()` but Linq query has older data. Why Linq query showing older data?
Here is the code.

```
studentViewLv.Clear();
studentViewLv.BeginUpdate();
var query = from c in context.StuBasics select c;
studentViewLv.Columns.Add("Ser No", 50);
studentViewLv.Columns.Add("Student Name ", 200);
studentViewLv.Columns.Add("Father's Name", 150);
studentViewLv.Columns.Add("Registration No", 150);
studentViewLv.Columns.Add("Class", 100);
studentViewLv.FullRowSelect = true;
int i = 1;
foreach (var c in query)
{
    string[] stu = new string[] { i.ToString(), c.firstName + " " + c.lastName, c.fatherName, c.registrationNo, c.currentClass };
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(stu);
    studentViewLv.Items.Add(item);
    i++;
}
studentViewLv.Refresh();
studentViewLv.Update();
studentViewLv.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: You could try the Refresh last, after EndUpdate has been called. Doesnt seem in the right order to me.

Comment: Tried that too. Not working.

Comment: have you checked to make sure the listview gets cleared before you populate it?

Comment: I'm calling it before updating the ListView, so I suppose it is getting cleared.

Comment: at what point does LINQ returns old items? from where do you call these snippet?

Comment: Inside foreach statement, "var c" is showing older data, but at the same point of time database already has updated its table before calling this method.

Comment: does `context.StuBasics` updated from database when method is called? you need to make sure data in this variable is updated

Comment: Yes I believe because when I call this the first time to populate ListView it works fine but for updates its not working.

Comment: If `context.StuBasics` is only populated when application is loaded then issue is here. You need to make sure to call it's update every time you perform actions with DB.  As LINQ in your sample is perfectly fine and alays retrieves latest data from `context.StuBasics`

Comment: So do I need to create new instance of context and use it here?

Comment: Problem solved. You were right. Saved my hours. Thanks.

Comment: what type of connection to database do you use? of what type is `context`? in most cases you just need to recall metho that reads data from database

Comment: I created a new instance of context and now it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from comments to clarify answer:

Does `context.StuBasics` updated from database when method is called? you need to make sure data in this variable is updated.

If `context.StuBasics` is only populated when application is loaded then issue is here. You need to make sure to call it's update every time you perform actions with DB. As LINQ in your sample is perfectly fine and alays retrieves latest data from `context.StuBasics`